# Addlayer method reloads screen and the white screen seems in Java desktop application using GeoTools

Tags: java, geotools, linestring, map-drawing, addlayer

I am trying to draw lines on map using GeoTools. Firstly I added a map layer, and while the program still is running, the user draws a line with mouse clicks. But every time addLayer method calls, the screen reloads again and the white screen seems for a while. I could not understand it is a Java desktop application problem or a geotools problem.

Here is the code. How can I prevent the reloads screen?

```
        File file = JFileDataStoreChooser.showOpenFile("shp", null);
        if (file == null) {
            return;
        }

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        // Create a map content and add our shapefile to it
        MapContent map = new MapContent();
        map.setTitle("Geotool application");

        Style style = SLD.createSimpleStyle(featureSource.getSchema());
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureSource, style);
        map.addLayer(layer);

        JMapFrame mapFrame = new JMapFrame(map);
        mapFrame.enableToolBar(true);
        mapFrame.enableStatusBar(true);
```

And the method to draw lines by coming mouse clicks.

```
public static void displayShapefile(File file, MapContent map, MapMouseEvent ev1, MapMouseEvent ev2, boolean isClicked) throws IOException, FactoryException, TransformException {

        GeometryFactory gf = JTSFactoryFinder.getGeometryFactory();

        double latitude, longitude, latitudeDest, longitudeDest;

        longitude = ev1.getWorldPos().x;
        latitude = ev1.getWorldPos().y;
        //  System.out.println("Enter destination longitude and latitude:\n");
        longitudeDest =  ev2.getWorldPos().x;
        latitudeDest = ev2.getWorldPos().y;

final String EPSG4326 = "GEOGCS[\"WGS 84\",DATUM[\"WGS_1984\",SPHEROID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\"," +
        "\"7030\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"6326\"]],PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"8901\"]],UNIT[\"degree\", " +
        "0.01745329251994328,AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"9122\"]],AUTHORITY[\"EPSG\",\"4326\"]]";
        CoordinateReferenceSystem crs = CRS.parseWKT(EPSG4326);


        Point start = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitude, latitude));
        Point end = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(longitudeDest, latitudeDest));

        GeodeticCalculator gc = new GeodeticCalculator(crs);
        gc.setStartingPosition(JTS.toDirectPosition(start.getCoordinate(), crs));
        gc.setDestinationPosition(JTS.toDirectPosition(end.getCoordinate(), crs));
        
        Coordinate[] coordinates = {start.getCoordinate(), end.getCoordinate()};
        LineString line = gf.createLineString(coordinates);

        FileDataStore store = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(file);
        SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource();

        SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder builder = new SimpleFeatureTypeBuilder();
        builder.setName("TwoDistancesType");
        builder.setCRS(DefaultGeographicCRS.WGS84);
        builder.add("line", LineString.class);

        final SimpleFeatureType TYPE = builder.buildFeatureType();

        SimpleFeatureBuilder featureBuilder = new SimpleFeatureBuilder(TYPE);
        featureBuilder.add(line);

        SimpleFeature feature = featureBuilder.buildFeature(null);
        DefaultFeatureCollection featureCollection = new DefaultFeatureCollection("internal", TYPE);
        featureCollection.add(feature);

        Style style = SLD.createLineStyle(Color.red, 2.0f);
        Layer layer = new FeatureLayer(featureCollection, style);

        map.addLayer(layer);
}
```

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/295425/draw-a-point-line-and-polygon-on-map-using-geotools answer your question more efficiently?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the code can draw lines, this is not my problem. I change DefaultFeatureCollection to your code, nothing did change.  In the code, I am drawing multiple lines but every map.addlayer() called the screen reloaded and the white screen comes for a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your screen refreshes slowly because of the number of things you are doing in your `displayShapefile` method.

1. get start and end points
2. parse a WKT string to get a projection
3. Initialise a Geodetic calculator
4. Add points to geodetic calculator
5. create a linestring
6. Look for a datastore
7. load a shapefile
8. create a featuretype
9. create a featurebuilder
10. build a feature
11. create a default featurecollection
12. create a simple style
13. create a layer
14. add layer to map

So obviously this all takes time, most of the steps are unneeded - you never use the `GeodeticCalculator`, you never use the shapefile you load. The schema, featurebuilder and style are identical every time you use the method, so why create them from new each time.

A far simpler idea would be to create a single layer based on a collection and add features to that layer each time you need to draw something.

If speed is really important then you need to rewrite the Swing MapPane to use a cached image for the base (or unchanging) layers and only redraw the changed layer on refresh. The GeoTools team welcomes PRs that implement new functionality like that.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me